# Replace entire contents of a file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

How do you replace the entire contents of a file in ruby?

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/data/**/*.json"].each do |f|
  encoded = f.read.force_encoding('UTF-16').encode('utf-8')
  # ????????
end
```

I'm trying to re-encode the contents of some json files.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/data/**/*.json"].each do |f|
  begin
    data = open(f, "r:utf-16:utf-8") {|fp| fp.read }
    open(f, "w") {|fp| fp << data }
  rescue Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError
    # Source data isn't in UTF-16, so skip this file.
    next
  end
end
```

The general idea is that we open the file as UTF-16, read it into a UTF-8-encoded string, then write it back (as UTF-8). The encoding parameters passed to `IO.open` take care of the conversions automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This creates some sample test data:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'json'

foo = {'a'=>%w[a b ç ∂]}
JSON.dump(foo, File.new('filein.json', 'w:UTF-16'))
```

"filein.json" looks like this when I `cat` it:

```
��{"a":["a","b","�","""]}
```

After creating that, either of these seem to work:

```
File.open('fileout.json', 'w:UTF-8') do |fo|
  File.open('filein.json', 'rb:UTF-16') do |fi|
    fo.write(fi.read)
  end
end
```

That simply does a read into memory with an immediate write; It's not scalable, but reasonable sized files should be handled OK. The input is read as UTF-16 and the output is written as UTF-8.

```
JSON.dump(
  JSON.load(File.open('filein.json', 'rb:UTF-16')),
  File.open('fileout.json', 'w:UTF-8')
)
```

This is similar to the previous sample, but it lets the JSON gem decode then re-encode the file. That might be useful, or it might not. And, again, it's not scalable because the read loads the file into memory.

For *BIG* files that exceed memory, or if you just want to do the right thing and use code that's scalable, use:

```
File.open('fileout.json', 'w:UTF-8') do |fo|
  File.foreach('filein.json', $/, encoding: 'UTF-16', mode: 'rb') do |li|
    fo.write(li)
  end
end
```

The output "fileout.json" created in all cases above was:

```
{"a":["a","b","ç","∂"]}
```

To use `Dir[]` to search, modify any of the examples by wrapping them like this:

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/data/**/*.json'].each do |filein|
  File.open(filein + '.new', 'w:UTF-8') do |fo|
    File.foreach(filein, $/, encoding: 'UTF-16', mode: 'rb') do |li|
      fo.write(li)
    end
  end
end
```

For every input file, that will generate a complimentary ".json.new" file. It's never safe to immediately overwrite your old files, so after running you can rename the `*.new` file however you want. I'd use:

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/data/**/*.json'].each do |filein|
  new_file = "#{ filein }.new"
  File.open(new_file, 'w:UTF-8') do |fo|
    File.foreach(filein, $/, encoding: 'UTF-16', mode: 'rb') do |li|
      fo.write(li)
    end
  end
  File.mv(filein, "#{ filein }.bak")
  File.mv(new_file, filein)
end
```